# MKS: Can you have multiple deferred checkins?

Tags: mks-integrity

By this I mean, are deferred checkins also versioned? Can I go back to a version I deferred earlier? Or does the checkin only mark a file for later checkin?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, at a time you can select multiple members to check-in in the SI Integrity.
Also, you checkin and checkout. Revisions will get updated.**

*Please refer below screenshot:*
[image]

Note:
You can simultaneously defer rename, move and/or checkin operations on a single member. When these deferred operations are submitted, Integrity Lifecycle Manager first performs the checkin operation followed by the rename operation, then the move operation. The sequence for performing these operations is set by default and is not configurable.

Comment: No I meant multiple deffered versions for the same file, not simply multiple files.

Comment: Yes, you can simultaneously defer rename, move and/or checkin operations on a single member. When these deferred operations are submitted, Integrity Lifecycle Manager first performs the checkin operation followed by the rename operation, then the move operation. The sequence for performing these operations is set by default and is not configurable.